# Whats the different between running ls doc*.txt and ls doc?*.txt and ls doc*?.txt in linux?

Tags: linux

When I run each of the commands below:

```
ls doc?*.txt
ls doc*?.txt
```

I get the same output as i do for simply running:

```
ls doc*.txt
```

Is there any difference between them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The globs in the commands:

```
ls doc?*.txt
ls doc*?.txt
```

...will not match the file name, `doc.txt`.

However...

```
ls doc*.txt
```

...will.  This is because the `?` in the first two globs means `exactly one character` while the `*` means `zero or more characters`.

In other words there needs to be at least one character between `doc` and `.txt` for the first two patterns to match.

The third pattern will match even if there are no characters between `doc` and `.txt`.

Comment: Thanks :) So while having only * means you can have 0 or more characters after doc, having the ? in there means you must have at least one other character. Does the order of ? and * matter?

Comment: No problems.  Remember to mark the question as answered :-)  Re: The difference, in this case, not really.  As a user of these globs, there no way real way to distinguish between `*?` and `?*`.  They both mean `at least one character`.  If you were to start looking into another type of pattern, a regular expression, the order may become important.  For globs, though...they're equivalent.